# Bottom N records with a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I want 10 oldest requests based on the received date ascending with a specific condition. I’m not sure how can I apply this on the calculation.
I have days pending already calculated in a table and I need to implement to get the 10 oldest pending requests by office and received date.

I have written this calculation

```
CALCULATE(SUM(table[days_pending]),
                FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),  
                    (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
                     table[Fiscal_Year] < MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]))))
```

but I’m not sure how can I get the 10 oldest received dates along with this condition
(table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
table[Fiscal_Year] < MAX(table[Fiscal_Year] applied.

Something like to convert this sql statement in powerbi syntax.

select top 10 office, received_date,  sum(days_pending) from table
where  Fiscal_Year_Closed >= '2024' and Fiscal_Year < '2024'
group by received_date, office
order by received_date asc

How can I go about achieving this? Thanks in advance!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: See `TOPN`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax

Comment: Use it as a filter in `CALCULATE`

Comment: Thanks, Marcus, for the suggestion. Following that link I wrote this syntax, however, its still not work fine.

SUMX(TOPN(10,
    SUMMARIZE(table,
                    table[received_date],
                      "Total_Days", CALCULATE(SUM(table[days_pending]),
                         FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),  
                           (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >=  MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
                             table[Fiscal_Year] < MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]))))
    ),
    [Total_Days], ASC),
    [Total_Days])

Comment: Hey Marcus, I have edited my initial question with the attachment. This is what I am trying to develop a table with 10 requests

Answer (score 0):

Add a new table to your model with the following:
Table Name: `Dim OldestPendingRequest`

| Column | Rank | Column sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10th Request and Number of Days Pending | 10 | 1 |
| 9th | 9 | 2 |
| 8th | 8 | 3 |
| 7th | 7 | 4 |
| 6th | 6 | 5 |
| 5th | 5 | 6 |
| 4th | 4 | 7 |
| 3rd | 3 | 8 |
| 2nd | 2 | 9 |
| Oldest Request and Number of Days Pending | 1 | 10 |

The table doesn't need to have any relationships created. Set the `Column` to be `Sort by...` `Column sort`.

Then create a measure with:

```
10 Oldest Pending Requests =
  var rowOrdinal = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim OldestPendingRequest'[Rank], 0)
  var preFilter = 
    FILTER(
      'table',  
      'table'[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= MAX('table'[Fiscal_Year]) && 
      'table'[Fiscal_Year] < MAX('table'[Fiscal_Year])
    )
  var oldestRows = TOPN(rowOrdinal, preFilter, [received_date], ASC)
  var neededRow = TOPN(1, oldestRows, [received_date], DESC)
  var result = CALCULATE(MIN(table[received_date]), neededRow) & UNICHAR(10) & CALCULATE(MIN(table[days_pending]), neededRow)
  RETURN IF(COUNTROWS(neededRow)>0, result)
```

Now you should be able to create a Matrix with:

- Rows: `table[office]`
- Columns: `'Dim OldestPendingRequest'[Column]`
- Values: `[10 Oldest Pending Requests]`

Comment: Thanks for helping! I created a new table Dim OldestPendingRequest as you have suggested above and then this measure 10 Oldest Pending Requests.
However, the visual goes blank while dragging this 'Dim OldestPendingRequest'[Column] to the column. 

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Goes total blank? You don't even see the column headers? Check to see if Power BI created any unwanted relationships to then`Dim OldestPendingRequest` table. Possible to share a sample PBIX to look at?

Comment: I double checked table is sitting separately without any relation. Yes, it goes complete blank. Let me see how can I share it.

Comment: I've tweaked the measure above, see if that helps.

Comment: Hey Sam, I have another question based on creating a simple table with office, received date based on this calculation.

CALCULATE(SUM(table[days_pending]),
                FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),  
                    (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
                     table[Fiscal_Year] < MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]))))

This calculation works fine with one column office. But numbers start repeating while adding the received date. Why? What do I need to do?

Comment: Since you have `ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office])` which means remove all context filters (even rows and columns) except for `[office]`. Just try `FILTER('table', ...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256185/discussion-between-josh-and-sam-nseir).

Comment: Direct FILTER('table', ...) doesn't work either. How can I share a dummy file with you to take a look at it as I need to resolve it. I mean I don't see any option to upload a file here.

Comment: Upload the file to a public share like OneDrive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc... then share the link to it.